# Use Maven-Project type job with Matrix (Multiconfiguration) plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, multi-configuration

Is it possible?

The `Maven project` job has some extra options (e.g. being able to use `Maven Repository Server plugin` or do an incremental build) that are not available in the *Invoke Top-Level Maven targets step*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. It's always like a freestyle one.

Comment: Although I came to the same conclusion as you some sources (e.g. a feature request) would improve your anwser